# Invalid From Key please refresh the page issue when product is addto cart Aws server using Magento 2.3.5p1?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I am using AWS server for Magento 2.3.5p1 installation.Everything is working fine when i use Mozilla Firefox.The issue is with Chrome browser.I am using php version 7.2 .
I have also increase the the following values to

```
max_input_vars = 200000
max_input_time = 600
max_execution_time = 3600
```

in php.ini file and restart the Apache.
Then also delete this from database.

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_path';
```

I have also checked the cookies configuration from admin and set to **Cookie Restriction Mode** to No.
Then i removed var and generated folder then upgrade and compile  then code